# What is this (Yogic) posture called?

Tags: yoga, identification-request

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUf6LeJS6ao) the boy is performing the act of Achamanam while sitting in a particular posture.

What is this Yogic posture called?

Is it the MridvAsana? (Sandhi: Mridu+Asana; with Mridu meaning soft).

NOTE: I have found mention of MridvAsana in scriptures.

Comment: I think you had already posted similar question

Comment: @RakeshJoshi No. I have shown this video to you earlier (in the Agama Chat room). That's how you remember it.

Comment: Gymnastic postures are not about the Hindu religion.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Who will decide what's in our religion and what's not? You..? Do u think that boy's Guru has told him to sit in that posture for nothing? Is he not part of some Sampradya (which he clearly is)? Are they not following scriptures?? Lessen ur arrogance and be humble and realize that there are many things that you still don't know about.

Comment: yes posture and mudras are vital part of upasana

Comment: Krishna condemns it in the Uddhava Gita.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I am not follower of Krishna. Adi Guru Lord Shiva prescribes it everywhere. He says a person who does not know the 84 basic Asanas is not fit to be a Guru. And i follow only him and Mother Goddess besides of course my own Gurus. If someone condemns Yoga (any form whether Raja or Hatha) i will simply ignore him.

Comment: And where exactly does Shiva say it?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda At many places in the Agamas he says so. In Agamic upasana, postures (Mudra+Asana) are vital. One full chapter of Nityoshodashika (Vamakeswara Tantram) is wholly dedicated to describing Mudras that are used in worship of Mahadevi. Will quote one such verse for you soon. Even in Puranic or Vedic Gayatri upasana, Mudras and postures assume vital role.

Comment: See Brahma Sutras 4.1.7-10

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda What Brahma Sutras?? Is'nt it just a man made scripture? It may be important for you but not so much for everyone else. Anyways here's a verse: **PadmAdi chaturashiti nAnAsana vichakshanah| YamAdyashtanga yogagyah sa guruh paramo matah ||** ...


One who is acquainted with padmasana etc 84 asanas and who knows yama etc ashtanga yoga, is recognised as the supreme guru. --- Anyways Lord Shiva actually said about not just 84 but 84 lakhs of asanas in Agamas. However, of them 84 are considered important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They call it the Kukkuta-Asana which is used while sipping the water. However, I feel that it is some kind of modification of that asana or a variant. Actual kukkutAsana is little difficult to do and both arms are engaged while doing it.

Quotes from ParamAchArya lecture,

> Achamana should always  be performed  sitting on the  clean ground .
>   The posture  unlike other rituals  is not on the lotus pose  but
>   Kukkuta (cock pose) , i.e  sitting down  on the  soles of the feet .It
>   is done always facing  the north   or east., The hands of   the person
>   doing it should  be in between his knees. The water   taken in the
>   hand should be pure, should not be hot nor scented and should not have
>   been touched  by hands. The right hand should be kept in such a way
>   that  forefinger  , middle finger  and  ring finger   are together
>   and slightly bent upwards. The little finger and thumb should be
>   separated from these  three  fingers. Using the sacrificial spoon 
>   (Udharani)   water should be taken by the   left hand and poured  in
>   the right hand. The water  thus poured should be held just  below the
>   thumb.
>   [Reference](http://brahminrituals.blogspot.ca/2016/06/achamanam-procedure-of-purification.html)

Comment: Actually that is not Kukkutasana. Because the boy is not sitting on both his soles. What Paramacharya is saying is about  sitting in squatting position. The boy is rather half "sitting on his haunches". He is sitting on his left haunch but his right foot sole is only on the ground not the left one.

Comment: They have not given the actual pic in the blog i suppose. Because the man doing the achamana.is simply sitting in. Sukhasana